# Find closest location with longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a application where I need to get nearby location, 
my web service will receive 2 parameters (decimal longitude, decimal latitude )

I have a table where the locations are saved in database with longitude and latitude fields,

I want to retrieve the nearest locations.

Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
 var locations = from l in locations

     select l
```

Here are further details about this :
i have a 2 fields (decimal(18, 2) null) 1 latitude, 2 longitude inside a database table,

and i have a method

```
public List<Locations>  GetLocation(decimal? Long, decimal? lat) 
{
var Loc = from l in Locations
  //// now here is how to get nearest location ? how to query?
  //// i have also tried Math.Abs(l.Lat - lat) its giving error about nullable decimal always hence i have seted decimal to nullable or converted to nullable
 //// also i have tried where (l.lat - Lat) * (l.lon - Long)  this is also giving error about can not convert decimal to bool
return Loc.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Code? Very brief... What have you tried sofar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is Solution

```
var constValue = 57.2957795130823D

var constValue2 = 3958.75586574D;

var searchWithin = 20;

double latitude = ConversionHelper.SafeConvertToDoubleCultureInd(Latitude, 0),
                    longitude = ConversionHelper.SafeConvertToDoubleCultureInd(Longitude, 0);
var loc = (from l in DB.locations
let temp = Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(l.Latitude) / constValue) *  Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(latitude) / constValue) +
                                 Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(l.Latitude) / constValue) *
                                 Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(latitude) / constValue) *
                                 Math.Cos((Convert.ToDouble(longitude) / constValue) - (Convert.ToDouble(l.Longitude) / constValue))
                             let calMiles = (constValue2 * Math.Acos(temp > 1 ? 1 : (temp < -1 ? -1 : temp)))
                             where (l.Latitude > 0 && l.Longitude > 0)
                             orderby calMiles

select new location
  {
     Name = l.name
  });
  return loc .ToList();
```

Comment: What are the constant values?

Comment: The name `ConversionHelper` doest not exist in current context. ,How to Solve?

Comment: l.Latitude > 0 && l.Longitude > 0 will only work in northern locations and to west of Greenwich meridian You can change from >0 to != 0

Comment: ConversionHelper is yet to be disclosed !!:)

Comment: @AbdullaSirajudeen I tried this and works:  double latitude = double.Parse(xxxxxx, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), longitude = double.Parse(yyyyyyy, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); where x and y are variables from input

Answer (score 63):

You could first convert the location data in database to `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate`, then use LINQ to find the nearest one.

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
var nearest = locations.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
                       .OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(coord))
                       .First();
```

Comment: +1 Nice find! I had to add reference to `System.Device` though, but works great! nice code thanks!

Comment: Brilliant answer, this. +1.

Comment: Does locations need to be in memory? in other words: is it possible to do this in pure Linq-To-Entities (translated to SQL)?

Comment: @sports No, I don't think the type `GeoCoordinate` and method `GetDistanceTo` is supported by the LINQ to Entities provider. I read about EF6 now support spatial type, [DbGeography.Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.spatial.dbgeography.distance(v=vs.113).aspx) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is this query still functional as today? Im getting a this error: The LINQ expression 'First()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. @Fung

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32130640/3200493), should be called `AsEnuemrable()` method before `OrderBy`, and it really works :D

Comment: Where do you find the System.Device library [dll] to install in VS 2017?

Comment: Love this approach!

Comment: How do I get this work on .NE Core 3.1, we don't have System.Device.Location in .NET Core 3.1

Comment: ended up using System.Device.Location.Portable 1.0.0

Comment: is `Locations` a datatable ? And what reference I need to use `GetDistanceTo´ ?

Comment: This does not compile `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type` on the line `locations.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))`

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on the comment by @Fung, if you are using Entity Framework / LINQ to Entities, if you try to use the `GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo` method in a LINQ query, you'll get a runtime NotSupportedException with the message:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double GetDistanceTo(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

With Entity Framework version 5 or 6, an alternative is to use the [System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) class. For example:

```
DbGeography searchLocation = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", longitude, latitude));

var nearbyLocations = 
    (from location in _context.Locations
     where  // (Additional filtering criteria here...)
     select new 
     {
         LocationID = location.ID,
         Address1 = location.Address1,
         City = location.City,
         State = location.State,
         Zip = location.Zip,
         Latitude = location.Latitude,
         Longitude = location.Longitude,
         Distance = searchLocation.Distance(
             DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + location.Longitude + " " + location.Latitude + ")"))
     })
    .OrderBy(location => location.Distance)
    .ToList();
```

`_context` in this example is your previously-instantiated DbContext instance.

Although it's currently [undocumented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the units returned by the [DbGeography.Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method appear to be meters.  See: [System.Data.Spatial DbGeography.Distance units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934169/system-data-spatial-dbgeography-distance-units)

Comment: The note about the distance type being in meters, instead of miles seems to be a really good bit of info. Thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a valid range, outside of which the "hit" is not really relevant?  If so, use

```
from l in locations where ((l.lat - point.lat) * (l.lat - point.lat)) + ((l.lng - point.lng) * (l.lng - point.lng)) < (range * range) select l
```

then find the hit with the smallest squared distance value within a loop of those results.

Comment: I don't think Euclidean distance comparison applies to longitude/latitude.

Comment: @sasjaq - True, but if we're talking about lat and lng points on this planet, and the distance being considered is short between two points such that the straight distance and the distance that wraps with the curvature of the Earth has a difference of say 1%, the flat approximation is good enough to perform the query for the closest well known point to a query point.

Comment: how to get the Range here for 500 meters?

Answer (score 1):

```
var objAllListing = (from listing in _listingWithLanguageRepository.GetAll().Where(z => z.IsActive == true)
                                     let distance = 12742 * SqlFunctions.Asin(SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (listing.Listings.Latitude - sourceLatitude)) / 2) * SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (listing.Listings.Latitude - sourceLatitude)) / 2) +
                                                        SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * sourceLatitude) * SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (listing.Listings.Latitude)) *
                                                        SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (listing.Listings.Longitude - sourceLongitude)) / 2) * SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (listing.Listings.Longitude - sourceLongitude)) / 2)))
                                     where distance <= input.Distance

                                     select new ListingFinalResult { ListingDetail = listing, Distance = distance }).ToList();//.Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.distance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A netcore friendly solution. Refactor as needed.

```
public static System.Drawing.PointF getClosestPoint(System.Drawing.PointF[] points, System.Drawing.PointF query) {
    return points.OrderBy(x => distance(query, x)).First();
}

public static double distance(System.Drawing.PointF pt1, System.Drawing.PointF pt2) {
    return Math.Sqrt((pt2.Y - pt1.Y) * (pt2.Y - pt1.Y) + (pt2.X - pt1.X) * (pt2.X - pt1.X));
}
```