# System.Data.Spatial DbGeography.Distance units?

Tags: c#, gps, entity-framework-5, spatial

When measuring the distance between two locations using the     `DbGeography.Distance(otherLocation)` what is the unit of the distance?

Even the msdn information and the intellisense fails to specify the unit of the distance.

Anyone knows?

[edit]
I'm using srid 4326. which most examples seems to use.
From what I can find, 4326 seems to be radians, this leaves me completely clueless.
radians are used to measure angles/degrees so what does this mean in reality ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Several articles seem to agree on meters being used in 4326 as the unit of distance.

WGS 84 is done in meters as well, which is probably why this uses meters.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-spatial-june-ctp.aspx
[http://www.jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2011/07/20/entity-framework-spatial-first-look.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-spatial-june-ctp.aspx)
http://blog.simplecode.eu/post/DistancesWithDbGeographyAndDbGeometry

Comment: For those of you dealing in miles your next question will be "How many meters in a mile?' Answer: 1609.344. Hope that saves you another search.

Comment: @grahamesd For those of you Americans... :p