# What is DbGeography return Distance unit?

Tags: c#, maps, spatial

When I am using the Distance method, it asks for 2 locations, and returns a double.

A double value that specifies the distance between the two closest points in geographyValue and otherGeography (MSDN).

But is it meters? kilometers? miles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Data.Spatial DbGeography.Distance units?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934169/system-data-spatial-dbgeography-distance-units)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this answer indicates meters:

[System.Data.Spatial DbGeography.Distance units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934169/system-data-spatial-dbgeography-distance-units)

the answerer has an srid of 4326. You can check what yours is in the DefaultCoordinateSystemId of your DbGeography object.