# how return a distance in dbgeography to km?

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5, spatial

this is the json result of calculate distance from current position to another placess in the list but i have a issue i can't convert distance unit (degree) to km from dbgeography.location.distance 
this is my code :

```
 string CurrentLocation = String.Format("POINT(" + CurrentLat + " " + CurrentLng + ")", 4326);
                DbGeography point = DbGeography.PointFromText(CurrentLocation, DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);

                var places = (from u in context.schoolinfo

                              orderby u.Location.Distance(point.Buffer(dist))

                              select u).Take(10).Select(x => new schoollinfo() { Name = x.name, Lat = x.Location.Latitude, Lng = x.Location.Longitude, Distance = x.Location.Distance(point.Buffer(dist)) }); ;

                var nearschools = places.ToList();
                return Json(nearschools, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[Print screen of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eFXj.png)

Comment: Does https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7350/converting-grid-resolution-from-degrees-to-kilometers or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934169/system-data-spatial-dbgeography-distance-units help?

Comment: @mjwills the first link it s interessant but it's still hard ..

Answer (score 1):

for calaculate a distance it's POINT(LONGITUDE LATITUDE) not POINT(LATITUDE LONGITUDE )so the code will change as this :

```
     select u).Take(10).Select(x => new schoollinfo() { Name = x.name, Lat = x.Location.Latitude, Lng = x.Location.Longitude, Distance = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + x.Location.Longitude + " " + x.Location.Latitude + ")", 4326).Distance(point) });
```