# Search by zip code and filter list within specific radius?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to figure out a way to take the following user input:

- Zip Code
- Distance (ex: 1,5,10) [miles]

And query against a List that contains:

- Location Name
- Zip Code
- Latitude
- Longitude

The filtered list should only return locations within a (x) mile radius of the inputted Zip Code & calculate distance for each (ex: 1.2 miles, 0.5 miles, etc). Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you already have the data, or are you asking if we know of an API you could use?

Comment: You can use LINQ to get the data you want

Comment: @christiandev  I have zip code, latitude, & longitude data each location (the list is pulled in from a database).

Comment: @Coder1409  Any examples?

Comment: This answer might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835851/find-closest-location-with-longitude-and-latitude

Comment: Given the large area covered by some US zip codes (99557 is over 13,000 sq miles), what does 1.2 miles away actually mean?

Comment: You need first to figure out the distance between two zip codes use latitude and longitude to calculate the distance and that is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding) to convert ZipCode into Latitude and Longitude at the client side. In an AJAX request we post lat, long and distance to server code. Server calculates offset using lat/long and radius, calculates from and to for latitude and longitude then searches the matching records.

```
if (!ValidaZipCode(zipCode)) {
    $("#searchZiperror").show();
    $(".driverZipcode").removeClass("wouterror");
    $(".driverZipcode").addClass("driverZipcodeError");
    return false;
}
else {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': zipCode }, function (results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     var currentlatlng = results[0].geometry.location;
     if (currentlatlng) {
         var lat = currentlatlng.lat();
         var lng = currentlatlng.lng();

         var model = {
             address: zipCode,
             latitude: lat,
             longitude: lng,
             radius: radiusValue
         };

         $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("UpdateRadius", "MyController")',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'html',
                 data: JSON.stringify(model)
             })
             .success(function (result) {
                 // Use the result for appropriate action
             })
             .error(function (xhr, status) {
                 // Use the status for appropriate action
             });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Thanks for your post!  While there are certainly many ways to approach this your response put me on a good path and gave me additional idea.  I ended up passing passing the Zip Code value to Google Geocoding API to get the corresponding latitude & longitudes values. With that I used the following function (http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/c-sharp) to calculate against the stirred list to determine distance.

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical point of view, you can do it, and there is a number of formulas to make the distance calculation (some resources here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html ).

But be aware that as the list increases, this becomes more and more expensive, because you'd have to use such formula against every element of the list.

Typically, to do this kind of operations (and many others) in an efficient way, it's used a GIS system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system some are open source or free, like PostgreSQL with a plugin if I am not wrong), which is specialized in this field.