# Linq does not recognize method GetDistanceTo

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this query which im attempting to sort by distance. However, linq is throwing me an error saying it does not recognize the method GetDistanceTo. The query works when the OrderBy clause is taken out.

```
 var coord = new GeoCoordinate { Latitude = (double?)array.latitude ?? 0, Longitude = (double?)array.longitude ?? 0 };

 var property = db.Properties.Select(x => new SearchResultsViewModel
 {
      geocoord = new GeoCoordinate { Latitude = (double?)x.latitude ?? 0, Longitude = (double?)x.longitude ?? 0 }

 }).OrderBy(x=>x.geocoord.GetDistanceTo(coord)).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried the [DbGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.110).aspx) class? Likely `GeoCoordinate` is not supported by LINQ to SQL.

Comment: That's because it doesn't know how to convert your custom method `GetDistanceTo` into SQL. You can add `.AsEnumerable()` before `.OrderBy()` to do the sorting in-memory, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to Entities has to translate your expression to a SQL query that can be executed against a database. It does not know how to translate `GetDistanceTo` into a SQL query.

You can call `AsEnumerable` before `OrderBy` to force ordering to be performed as in-memory LINQ to Objects query.

```
 var property = db.Properties.Select(x => new SearchResultsViewModel
 {
      geocoord = new GeoCoordinate { Latitude = (double?)x.latitude ?? 0, Longitude = (double?)x.longitude ?? 0 }

 }).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.geocoord.GetDistanceTo(coord)).ToList();
```