# Get the Range of Lat Long with in specified Radius in c#

Tags: c#, geolocation, geometry

I am working on a website in which I have the User's Location Lat and Long saved in my **Location** table. Now I want to use a filter **SearchByDistance** which have values: **5km**, **10km**, **15km** through which the user can get the results according to the specified Range.

Now what I actually wants to do is to get the input from the user say **5km** and get the results from my table which falls with in the range of user's saved **LatLong** in the **Location** table and 5km to that **LatLong**. I google on this and found some links like:

*[How do I find the lat/long that is x km north of a given lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125144/how-do-i-find-the-lat-long-that-is-x-km-north-of-a-given-lat-long)*

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx*

But I am unable to get my requirement from the above. Please help. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478874/find-all-nearby-customers-within-a-given-distance-using-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach can be, first create a circle (your center will be user lat and long) with the given radius say 5KM or 10Km and then find the rows from the Polygon Rings. I wrote it for esri maps. Hope it will solve your problem

```
Polygon areaOfInterset;

void CreateCircle(double radius)
{
    var point = new MapPoint(Your Lat and Long);// This will be user lat and long on which you want to draw a circle

    var graphic = new Graphic();
    var circle = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection();
    int i = 0;

    while (i <= 360)
    {
        double degree = (i * (Math.PI / 180));
        double x = point.X + Math.Cos(degree) * radius;
        double y = point.Y + Math.Sin(degree) * radius;
        circle.Add(new MapPoint(x, y));
        i++;
    }
    var rings = new ObservableCollection<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection> { circle };
            areaOfInterset = new Polygon { Rings = rings};
}
```

Now next task is to find the rows. For that you can use below code inside the loop.

```
foreach(MapPoint selectedRow in DatabaseRowsToBeSearched)
{
   var isExist = IsInsideCircle(selectedRow)
}

bool IsInsideCircle(MapPoint location)
{
    var isInside = false;
    foreach (var shape in areaOfInterset.Rings)
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = shape.Count - 1; i < shape.Count; j = i++)
        {
            if ((((shape[i].Y <= location.Y) && (location.Y < shape[j].Y)) ||
                ((shape[j].Y <= location.Y) && (location.Y < shape[i].Y))) &&
                (location.X < (shape[j].X - shape[i].X) * (location.Y - shape[i].Y) / (shape[j].Y - shape[i].Y) + shape[i].X))
            {
                isInside = !isInside;
            }
        }
    }

    return isInside;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not upto my requirement. In the second piece of code you are finding the User's Location, but I already have the User's current location(LatLong) saved in my Table. My requirement is to just plus the radius say 5km in the User's LatLong and find the rows that falls between these LatLong range. I hope I am able to explain it clearly

Comment: I have applied your code my not success. Is this not possible to plus the user's input in the User's LatLong saved in the db. I this we will get the range of MinLatLong and MaxLatLong. With this we can easily fire the query in LINQ to get the no of records that falls within these two ranges